# how to create a dictionary from a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a Python code that will allow me to take in text, and read it line by line. In each line, the words just go into the dictionary as a key and the numbers should be the assigned values, as a list. 
 the file 'topics.txt' will be composed of hundreds of lines that have the same format as this:

```
1~cocoa
2~
3~
4~
5~grain~wheat~corn~barley~oat~sorghum
6~veg-oil~linseed~lin-oil~soy-oil~sun-oil~soybean~oilseed~corn~sunseed~grain~sorghum~wheat
7~
8~
9~earn
10~acq
```

and so on..
i need to create dictionaries for each word
for ex:
Ideally, the name "grain" would be a key in the dictionary, and the values would be dict[grain]: [5,6,..].
similarly,
"cocoa" would be another key and values would be 
dict[cocoa]:[1,..]
Not much,but so far..

```
with open("topics.txt", "r") as fi:  # Data read from a text file is a string
    d = {}
    for i in fi.readlines():
        temp = i.split()
        #i am lost here
        num = temp[0]
        d[name] = [map(int, num)]
```

Comment: You have explained your goal, but you don't seem to have asked any questions. What is your question?

Comment: i am not able to create the dictionaries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

```
import collections

with open('topics.txt') as f:
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        value, *keys = line.strip().split('~')
        for key in filter(None, keys):
            d[key].append(value)
```

`value, *keys = ...` is [Extended Iterable Unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) which is only available in Python 3.x.

Comment: Note that the `value, *keys = ...` syntax works in Python 3 only.

Comment: @nooodl, This question is tagged with `python-3.x`.

Comment: It is, but I thought that'd be a useful little piece of information nonetheless (what if someone stumbled upon this question and wondered why this answer didn't work for them?)

Comment: @nooodl, I added a link to  Extended Iterable Unpacking. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: thank you!and how do i count the number of elements in each dictionary?

Comment: What difference does it make by using filter? How is it different than 'for key in keys:'?

Comment: @shantanoo, `filter` was used to exclude empty keys: `list(filter(None, ['key1', '', 'key2']))` -> `['key1', 'key2']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("topics.txt", "r") as file:  # Data read from a text file is a string
    dict = {}
    for fullLine in file:
        splitLine = fullLine.split("~")
        num = splitLine[0]
        for name in splitLine[1:]:
            if name in dict:
                dict[name] = dict[name] + (num,)
            else
                dict[name] = (num,)
```

Comment: Look more carefully: The same word occurs on multiple lines. Your code doesn't handle that.

Comment: @alexis Thanks, I didn't notice that.